# Error occurs - "Could not find or load main class ", when run a topology on Storm official docker 1.2.1

Tags: java, maven, docker, runtime-error, apache-storm

I pulled the latest docker image from Docker Hub for Storm 1.2.1. And packaged the storm-starter example project from Storm source code 1.2.1 according to the README documentation under the project, and renamed the package as "topology.jar". But when I submitted the jar file into Storm docker with

`$ docker run -it -v $(pwd)/topology.jar:/topology.jar storm storm jar /topology.jar org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology`,

the error occurred:

> Running: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin/java -client -Ddaemon.name= -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/apache-storm-1.2.1 -Dstorm.log.dir=/logs -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /apache-storm-1.2.1/*:/apache-storm-1.2.1/lib/*:/apache-storm-1.2.1/extlib/*:/topology.jar:/conf:/apache-storm-1.2.1/bin -Dstorm.jar=/topology.jar -Dstorm.dependency.jars= -Dstorm.dependency.artifacts={} org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology
>   Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology

And I added a HelloWorld class under the same package as the ExclamationTopology is which just print "Hello world!" in the main method:

`public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }`

When I submit this new package with `$ docker run -it -v $(pwd)/topology.jar:/topology.jar storm storm jar /topology.jar org.apache.storm.starter.HelloWorld`, it printed "Hello world!" as expected.

So what is the problem? Any help is appreciated.

PS.

- /META-INFO/MANIFEST.MF in the topology.jar

  ```
  Manifest-Version: 1.0
  Implementation-Title: storm-starter
  Implementation-Version: 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
  Built-By: leo
  Specification-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
  Specification-Title: storm-starter
  Implementation-Vendor-Id: org.apache.storm
  Implementation-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
  Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
  Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_121
  Specification-Version: 2.0
  Implementation-URL: http://storm.apache.org/examples/storm-starter
  ```
- When executed as `jar -tvf topology.jar | grep ExclamationTopology`.  The console printed

> 2060 Mon Mar 05 11:40:08 CST 2018 org/apache/storm/starter/ExclamationTopology.class
>     2242 Mon Mar 05 11:40:08 CST 2018 org/apache/storm/starter/ExclamationTopology$ExclamationBolt.class

- classpath is printed as above when the error occurred which follow the `-cp` keyword. And project structure of storm-starter is the same as the official master branch in Github. Besides, HelloWorld class shares the same package with ExclamationTopology which is `org.apache.storm.starter`. You can refer the source code here [storm-starter](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter).

Comment: We will need more information on the manifest file in topology.jar, class path and main class in that jar, and any more context on directory structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it. The official docker image on Docker Hub for Storm 1.2.1 misses the class called `ConfigurableTopology`. Copy it from storm-client as the local one, then recompile the package. You can submit it successfully.

Comment: Can you explain it in more details as I am facing a similar issue